# Can I define CellTemplate of DataGrid as a Resource so that it can be reused in multiple columns?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, silverlight-4.0, celltemplate

I want a specific template for all my columns in DataGrid. The usual method is I will replicate the entire XAML for DataTemplate multiple times in the DataGrid in each of the Column.

Is there any way I can define the CellTemplate globally as a resource and then just pass the the "Path" property of "Binding" to it, so that it displays the correct item from the DataContext ?

Is this possible ?

Comment: Markup Extension, in a hacky way may be the solution. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23106619/2279200), which originates from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7170525/2279200)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create DataTemplate in App.Xaml file with key/name.

```
 <DataTemplate x:Name="myTemplate" TargetType="sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName}" BorderThickness="0"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding LastName}" BorderThickness="0"/>
                </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
```

Now you can use this template in DataGrid like

```
 <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" CellTemplate={StaticResource myTemplate}>
```

OR
    You can to pass Binding Path name in code behind like...

```
        string colPath = "FirstName";
        DataGrid grid = new DataGrid();
        grid.ItemsSource = myViewModel.EmpCollection;

        DataGridTemplateColumn column = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
        DataTemplate itemTemplate = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load("<DataTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007\"> <ContentPresenter Content=\"{Binding Path=" + colPath + "}\"  /></DataTemplate>");

        column.CellTemplate = itemTemplate;
        grid.Columns[0] = column;
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I need to pass the Binding Path into DataTemplate from actual DataGridTemplateColumn, otherwise there will be a need of 7 different DataTemplates for having 7 columns in DataGrid, which is no better than writing 7 times the same XAML. Here, in your example, I need to pass FirstName somewhere from actual TemplateColumn and it should be available in DataTemplate.

Comment: Hi Punit, if you can use Code behind to add DataGrid or assign column to your datagrid then I think you are fine to do it.

Comment: Actually, I was looking for a XAML solution, I knew I can do it like this in code behind. Anyways, because there are no responses, I believe we can not do it in XAML as of now.