# Create Common DataGridTemplateColumn in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagridtemplatecolumn

I need to create a common `DataGridTemplateColumn`, so that I can use it across my application with different objects and properties.

here is some sample code, I use in my project

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="100*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Age}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>   
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Age}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I need a generic version of the code so that I can place the `DataTemplate` in `app.xaml` and reference it in my code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I define CellTemplate of DataGrid as a Resource so that it can be reused in multiple columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354650/can-i-define-celltemplate-of-datagrid-as-a-resource-so-that-it-can-be-reused-in)

Answer (score 8):

You can't template `DataGridTemplateColumn` directly. But fortunately you can use global templates for *cells*. Take a look at example:

**App.xaml**

```
<Application.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="CellEdintingTemplate">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Age}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CellTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Age}" />
    </DataTemplate>

</Application.Resources>
```

**Using**

```
    <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn 
                 CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource CellEdintingTemplate}" 
                 CellTemplate="{StaticResource CellTemplate}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```